# iPhone SDK: Memory leak in assiging property values?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I have a leakage in my connectionDidFinishLoading class how can fix this?

[image]

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableData *responseXMLData;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSMutableData *lastLoadedResponseXMLData;

-(void)dealloc {
[responseXMLData release] ;
responseXMLData=nil;
[lastLoadedResponseXMLData release];
lastLoadedResponseXMLData=nil;
[super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: which type is the leaked object according to instruments? is it `NSMutableData`? could you check if you access somewhere `lastLoadedResponseXMLData` or `responseXMLData` directly (without using the property, I mean, and except for the release you are doing)?

Comment: pretty sure you need to change your lastLoadedResponseXMLData property to retain instead of copy if you plan on changing it after setting it the first time.

Comment: @matt thx what you advised solved my problem, create an answer and I can accept it

Comment: @sergio tnx sergio, I checked but couldnt find a direct access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSMutableData *lastLoadedResponseXMLData;
```

Since you are working with a mutable object that you are going to be setting and changing, you should use RETAIN:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableData *lastLoadedResponseXMLData;
```

retain - "Specifies that retain should be invoked on the object upon assignment. ... The previous value is sent a release message." So you can imagine assigning an NSString instance (which is an object and which you probably want to retain).

copy - "Specifies that a copy of the object should be used for assignment. ... The previous value is sent a release message." Basically same as retain, but sending -copy rather than -retain.

Here is some good reading on the various get/set methods you can instruct @property/@synthesize to create for you: http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/06/assign-retain-copy-pitfalls-in-obj-c.html

Answer (score 1):

you did not tell us where you are creating the object for responseXMLData? where ever you are initializing that object should release that

```
self.responseXMLData = [[NSMutuableData alloc]init]autorelease];
```

and in your dealloc method you could have just say

```
-(void)dealloc {

    self.responseXMLData = nil; //which is equivalent to [responseXMLData release]; responseXMLData=nil;
}
```

and

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, in your:

```
self.lastLoadedResponseXMLData = nil;
self.lastLoadedResponseXMLData = self.responseXMLData;
```

Before one release happens at dealloc, could there be a possible where your just set to nil and copy next responseXMLData to lastLoadedResponseXMLData without releasing any previous copies?